# Changing the Default Dashboard in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have lots of web sites on Google Analytics. Is it possible to create a default dashboard for all web sites inside an account?

I usually have the same needs of data for all my web sites. Now, I am defining the dashboard for each and every web site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can share the customization of your dashboard with other accounts

> Permalinks let you share the customizations you have made to
>   dashboards, advanced segments, and reports. When you share a
>   customization, you share only the settings for that customization--you
>   do not share any data.

To share your customization of a dashboard:

http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2485195

The page has mostly screen shots not really something I can type up for you